# how to convert string into Date only in C# asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datetime, telerik

I have get Date from Telerik Date component and passed it to asp.net controller using javaScript but i am not able to convert date because there is run time error that String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
<%:Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name("name")%>

 $.ajax({
            url: '<%=Url.Action("funx","Home")%>',
            data: { idd: id, dtt: datepicker },
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
}
)};
```

Controller funx

```
public JsonResult funx(int idd, string dtt)
        {
DateTime dte= DateTime.ParseExact(dtt.Substring(1, 24),
                             "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 //   DateTime dte = DateTime.Parse(dtt.ToString());
}
```

Comment: why you taken dtt.Substring(1, 24)?

Comment: @ram What `dtt` value you are getting? can you  show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have written a comment, but I still don't have enough reputation.

In which format are you getting the date from the datepicker?

```
String datePickerInput = "31.07.2015";
String format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
DateTime dte = DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The format-String is used to tell the DateTime in which format the given String is formatted, as you can see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are converting it to a DateTime. The DateTime contains all possible time units altough you might not need it. If you want to parse it to a String again use the '.ToString(format)' method from DateTime. For example: `dte.ToString('dd.MM.yyyy')`
If you want another format look here: [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx